# Calculating time complexity using master method

Tags: time-complexity

Can anyone explain the time complexity of the below using the master method?

```
int sum(Node node) {
    if (node == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    return sum(node.left) + node.value + sum(node.right);
}
```

I know a's value is 2 but its hard for me to identify b and d. Is b=1 and d=cO(n)? In that case can anyone explain how b and d should be identified

Comment: what and where is `a` in your code?

Comment: A is the number of sub problems, B is the size of each sub problem and D is f(n)(i.e.) the cost of work that is done outside of the recursive call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, to make the recurrence relation less complicated, we can assume a balanced binary tree that has `2^i`nodes, so we obtain a recurrence of `T(n) = 2T(n/2) + 1` (ignoring the base case).

From above, we can find *a* = 2, *b* = 2, and *c* = 0, since 1 is O(1). Applying the master method, it passes case 1 and we can get our complexity as **T(n) = Θ(n<sup>log<sub>2</sub>2</sup>) or O(n)**

Answer (score 0):

This is a function used to sum up all nodes in a binary tree. First down from root to leave and then goes up (stack unwinding). So, time complexity is O(N), as it needs to visit each node at least once.